# PHP prepared statement errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to learn to use prepared statements in PHP. I can not figure out why my prepare fails every time. I have a small table set up with three columns. The table is `Test`. 
columns are

```
A_ID, FirstName, LastName
A_ID id an auto increment
```

.

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
echo "The prepared statement failed to connect ERROR: (" . $connection- >connect_errno . ") " . $connection->connect_error;

}


$FirstName = $_GET["FirstName"];
$LastName = $_GET["LastName"];

echo $FirstName . ", " . $LastName . "<hr>";

if (!($stmt = $connection -> prepare("INSERT INTO Test (FirstName, LastName) 
                                    VALUES (?,?)"))); { 
 echo "Prepare failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;
 echo "<hr>";
//$stmt->debugDumpParams();
}


var_dump($stmt);
echo "<hr>";
if (!$stmt->bind_param ("ss", $FirstName, $LastName)) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
  echo "return : " . $stmt->affected_rows;
  $stmt->close();


$connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: eh a misplaced ;  ugg.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an syntactical error here with a irrelevant `;`:

```
if (!($stmt = $connection -> prepare("INSERT INTO Test (FirstName, LastName) 
                                   VALUES (?,?)"))); { //rest of the code
```

which should have been like:

```
if (!($stmt = $connection -> prepare("INSERT INTO Test (FirstName, LastName) 
                                   VALUES (?,?)"))) { //rest of the code
```

Comment: rogue ;   thanks for the help.